# R First Non-NA Value From Cols

Tags: r, data.table, coalesce

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                CO=c(-6,4,2,3,0,2),
                CATFOX=c(1,NA,NA,3,0,NA),
                DOGFOX=c(NA,NA,5,1,2,NA),
                RABFOX=c(NA,3,NA,5,3,NA),
                D=c(0,4,5,6,1,2),
                WANT=c(1,3,5,3,0,NA))
```

I have a dataframe and i wish to make column `WANT` take the first value of 'CATFOX' 'DOGFOX' 'RABFOX' that is not NA. Is there a `data.table` solution? I tried this but it did not produce the desired outcome:

`df$WANT=do.call(coalesce, data[grepl('FOX',names(data))])`

Comment: @akrun maybe you have a suggestion?

Comment: thanks, i posted a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a vectorized option in `base R`

```
i1 <- endsWith(names(df), 'FOX')
df$WANT2 <-  df[i1][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), max.col(!is.na(df[i1]), 'first'))]
df$WAN2
#[1]  1  3  5  3  0 NA
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `coalesce` in your example which is `dplyr`'s construct. Try `fcoalesce`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, WANT2 := fcoalesce(CATFOX, DOGFOX, RABFOX)]
```

Output:

```
   ID CO CATFOX DOGFOX RABFOX D WANT WANT2
1:  1 -6      1     NA     NA 0    1     1
2:  2  4     NA     NA      3 4    3     3
3:  3  2     NA      5     NA 5    5     5
4:  4  3      3      1      5 6    3     3
5:  5  0      0      2      3 1    0     0
6:  6  2     NA     NA     NA 2   NA    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this `base R` solution:

```
#Data
data=data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                CO=c(-6,4,2,3,0),
                CATFOX=c(1,NA,NA,3,0),
                DOGFOX=c(NA,NA,5,1,2),
                RABFOX=c(NA,3,NA,5,3),
                D=c(0,4,5,6,1),
                WANT=c(1,3,5,3,0))
#Process
index <- which(names(data) %in% c('CATFOX','DOGFOX','RABFOX'))
data$WANT2 <- apply(data[,index],1,function(x) x[min(which(!is.na(x)))])
```

Output:

```
  ID CO CATFOX DOGFOX RABFOX D WANT WANT2
1  1 -6      1     NA     NA 0    1     1
2  2  4     NA     NA      3 4    3     3
3  3  2     NA      5     NA 5    5     5
4  4  3      3      1      5 6    3     3
5  5  0      0      2      3 1    0     0
```